# Inserting a Google Chart inside its own HTML column without overflowing other columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

My HTML page has two columns. A left column of fixed width, and a right column with the remaining width. What I write in the left column should remain on the left side, what I write in the right column should remain on the right.

**Columns work fine with text at least**
[image: This is the expected behaviour of columns in my document]

I am trying to insert a Google Pie Chart in the right column. But it is not working: the image overlaps the left column.

**The pie chart overlaps and hides part of the left column. That's not what I want.**
[image: Bug: the pie chart overlaps the left column and it should not]

What's wrong?

This is my HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload=display()>
<title>Test</title>
<div class="leftimage">
LEFT IMAGE<br>
...    
</div>
<div id="rightwork">
RIGHT WORK
Blah blah blah just filling with some text we don't care about
...
</div>

<div class="footer">
FOOTER
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the relevant parts of my CSS:

```
.leftimage {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
}

.rightwork { 
             width: auto;
             overflow: hidden;
}
```

And this is my javascript. Note that the first few functions are to ensure that the google charts library is loaded. I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it works.

```
function load_google_charts() {
    console.log("loading google charts library...");
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Charts library is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(set_google_charts);
}

var google_charts_loaded = false;
if (! google_charts_loaded) {
    load_google_charts();
}

function set_google_charts() {
    console.log("google charts library is loaded");
    google_charts_loaded = true;
}

function display() {
    var pieData = new Array(['Sample','Score'],
                ['A', 10], 
                ['B', 40]);
    if (! google_charts_loaded) {
    load_google_charts();
    }
    if (google_charts_loaded) {
        var chartdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(pieData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("rightwork"));
        chart.draw(chartdata);
    }
}
```

In the end, you see that I insert the pie chart in the 'rightwork' element of my HTML page, which is meant to be the right column of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reducing the chart's `z-index`, this will send it back...

And it looks like you need to change the selector in the css, since you're using `id`

```
#rightwork { 
   width: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: it was simply the selector for rightwork: #rightwork and not .rightwork. 
How silly! Thanks.